# Reciprocal in r studio

Tags: r, regression

my supervisor asked me to do reciprocal for my gamma distribution models. He said it's the default and I am not quite sure what he means. Does it mean if I don't specify a "link=" that it will automatically use reciprocals for my gamma distribution? Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your supervisor is asking you to fit a Gamma GLM with an *inverse link*, `g(x) = 1/x`.  This is indeed the default value: if you look at `?Gamma` (i.e. the help file for the `Gamma()` family function) you'll see

> Gamma(link = "inverse")

which indicates that the inverse (or reciprocal) is the default. So

```r
glm(y ~ x, data = ..., family = Gamma())
```

and

```r
glm(y ~ x, data = ..., family = Gamma(link = "inverse"))
```

should give you exactly the same answer.

Comment: Or maybe to model something with an inverse gamma prior?

Comment: @ChristophHanck: possible but seems less likely. OP refers to a link function, and to the default value, so ...